# How can I clip INSIDE a shape in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: canvas, clipping

I've found a number of examples for clipping the *outside* region of an arc (e.g.: [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jimrhoskins/Sv87G/1/)).  I can't seem to figure out how to clip *inside* the arc shape instead.

Here is an example of how I'm currently clipping the outside region, which is essentially the opposite of what I want:

```
ctx.save();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
ctx.clip();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth     = 1;
ctx.shadowBlur    = 10;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = shadowOffset;
ctx.shadowColor   = '#000000';
ctx.strokeStyle   = '#000000';
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.restore();
```

Comment: do you have a picture of what your desired code should result in?

Comment: Yes, as @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans says, could you explain better what "clip inside" means to you?  It can't be as simple as drawing your canvas sized image and then drawing your blue circle over that image.

Comment: In the example I posted, the clipping is happening outside the arc.  In other words, areas outside of the arc are being clipped (removed).  I want the opposite of that, where the areas inside the arc are clipped (removed) instead, with the areas outside the arc still rendered normally.

Answer (score 18):

## Available options

For irregular shapes you can use two techniques:

1. Composite mode
2. Clipping

IMHO the better choice to use the actual clipping mode or the composite mode `destination-out`.

As markE says in his answer `xor` is available too, but xor only inverts alpha pixels and doesn't remove the RGB pixels. This works for solid images with no transparency, but where you have existing pixels with transparency these might give you the opposite effect (becoming visible) or if you later use xor mode with something else drawn on top the "clipped" area will show again.

### Clipping

By using clipping you can simply use `clearRect` to clear the area defined by the path.

**Example:**

```
/// save context for clipping
ctx.save();

/// create path
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.closePath();

/// set clipping mask based on shape
ctx.clip();

/// clear anything inside it
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, offset, offset);

/// remove clipping mask
ctx.restore();
```

**[ONLINE DEMO FOR CLIPPING](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/HZVtf/)**

**Source image**: an image that has partial semi-transparent pixels and full transparent where the white from background comes through -

[image: Source image]

**Result:**

We punched a hole in it and the background shows through:

[image: clipping]

### Composite mode: destination-out

Using composite mode `destination-out` will clear the pixels as with clipping:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(offset * 0.5, offset * 0.5, offset * 0.3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.closePath();

/// set composite mode
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
ctx.fill();

/// reset composite mode to default
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
```

**[ONLINE DEMO FOR COMPOSITE MODE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/PaRPs/)**:

**Result:**

[image: destination out]

Same as with clipping as `destination-out` removes the pixels.

### Composite mode: xor

Using `xor` in this case where there exists transparent pixels ([see online example here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/zV9uJ/)):

[image: xor mode]

Only the alpha values was inverted. As we don't have solid pixels the alpha won't go from 255 to 0 (`255 - 255`) but `255 - actual value` which result in non-cleared background using this mode.

(if you draw a second time with the same mode the "removed" pixels will be restored so this can be utilized in other ways).

Answer (score 10):

You surely can clip using the 'inverted' clip shape of your style : just draw first the
screen outline, then draw your clipping path -without using beginPath-, then  close the path and clip.
This way the shape you describe is a 'hole' within the screen.
The path function must describe a closed path.

A demo is here : http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/9DuJL/40/
We can see that it works even with several shapes,
provided they do not intersect.

[image: example of std clip]

[image: example of revert clip]

The code looks like :

```
// clips the canvas with the invert of provided path function
// if pathFunction is an array, remove clips defined by all functions
function clipRevert(pathFunction) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    if (Array.isArray(pathFunction)) pathFunction.forEach(execute);
    else pathFunction();
    ctx.clip();
}


function execute(fn) {
    return fn();
}
```

example of use : (will draw an image using reversed clip of a circle) :

```
function circlePath(x, y, r) {
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
}

window.clipRevertExample = function () {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    clipRevert(circlePath.bind(null, 100, 60, 40));
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Last remark : you can in fact choose an arbitrary base shape to substract from.

Answer (score 2):

You can use context.globalCompositeOperation="xor" to remove from your existing image based on any path or drawing.

This compositing mode will "undraw" the existing pixels using any drawing you do after applying the compositing.

In this case, the existing image will be "undrawn" based on your arc:

[image]

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/9DuJL/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="xor";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(106, 77, 74, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}
img.src="http://i.imgur.com/gwlPu.jpg";


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=158></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```