# HTML5 How to call image in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have design a canvas now I want to call a image in that canvas. I have gone through the tutorials but I don't know how to implement that. My image is high resolution but I want to reduce that image size and resolution with javascript. Anybody will help me.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();

ctx.moveTo(8,200);
ctx.lineTo(8,308);
ctx.moveTo(259,76);
ctx.lineTo(259,308);
ctx.moveTo(259,308);
ctx.lineTo(8,308);
ctx.moveTo(8,200);
ctx.lineTo(259,76);
ctx.stroke();
var imageObj = new Image();

  imageObj.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'img/logo.jpg', height='42', width='42';
</script>
```

I am not able to call image. Anybody will help me how to convert this javascript in jquery?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "call image"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add image to canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011378/how-to-add-image-to-canvas)

Comment: @Amadan I want to display image in canvas only. Like a picture frame

Comment: In that case, +1 to @Mr.Alien.

Comment: @Mr.Alien yeah the same question. but will you help me to display image in same canvas shape in my question?

Comment: @VaibhavDass You already have the solution, spoon feeding won't help you

Comment: @Mr.Alien I trying but I am not getting any error so finally I posted here.

Comment: This question is a duplicate question, but not to the linked dup (the linked dup does not include resizing as the questioner desires).  Anyway, to draw a resized image on the canvas you can use this form of `drawImage`: ctx.drawImage(imageObj,69,50,42,42);

Comment: Thank you @markE it helps. But I want to use canvas as my picture frame also. I want to remove all the outer part from the canvas. how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following syntax if you want to resize the image too.

```
context.drawImage(img,x-Position,y-Position,width,height);
```

Here is an Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xV5Sb/) as an example.

You can read more about `drawImage` function in this [W3CSchool's article](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp).

Comment: Hi Shiva, you have solved my problem, but now the issue is I am not able to use canvas as a picture frame I change this line "ctx.drawImage(imageObj,100, 160, 100, 100);" to "ctx.drawImage(imageObj,9, 58, 250, 250);" now how do I remove the outer part of the image from the canvas border? will you help me?

Comment: @VaibhavDass: vaibhav please refer to this post, probably its what yoy are trying to achieve.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988118/how-can-i-clip-inside-a-shape-in-html5-canvas
In it do see the Jsfiddle in 'GameAlchemist''s answer